# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity - Append to JSON File

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am working on creating a data factory pipeline that copies data from a REST API endpoint to Azure Blob Storage. The API has a limitation of only returning 1000 records at a time, so I have built in a loop into my pipeline that will iterate through all of the pages. What I am wondering is - would it be possible to use the copy activity to append to the same file in the Azure Blob, rather than create a separate file for each page?

Below is what the API response looks like. The only value that I need from each response is the "records" list, so I was thinking if it is possible, I could get rid of the other stuff and just keep appending to the same file as the loop runs - although I do not know if the copy activity is capable of doing this. Would this be possible? Or is the only way to do this is to land all the responses as separate files in Blob Storage and then combine them after the fact?

Thank You

```
{
    "totalResults": 8483,
    "pageResults": 3,
    "timeStamp": "2020/08/24 10:43:26",
    "parameters": {
        "page": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 3,
        "filters": [],
        "fields": [
            "lastName",
            "firstName",
            "checklistItemsAssigned",
            "checklistItemsStarted",
            "checklistItemsCompleted",
            "checklistItemsOverdue"
        ],
        "sort": {
            "field": "lastName",
            "direction": "asc"
        }
    },
    "records": [
        {
            "checklistItemsAssigned": 10,
            "lastName": "One",
            "firstName": "Person",
            "checklistItemsOverdue": 0,
            "checklistItemsStarted": 10,
            "checklistItemsCompleted": 10
        },
        {
            "checklistItemsAssigned": 5,
            "lastName": "Two",
            "firstName": "Person",
            "checklistItemsOverdue": 0,
            "checklistItemsStarted": 5,
            "checklistItemsCompleted": 5
        },
        {
            "checklistItemsAssigned": 5,
            "lastName": "Three",
            "firstName": "Person",
            "checklistItemsOverdue": 0,
            "checklistItemsStarted": 5,
            "checklistItemsCompleted": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF's Copy activity supports copying blobs from block, append, or page type of blobs but copying data to **only** block blobs. Blobk blobs can only be overwritten.
You can probably create an append type of blob using Storage SDK, but it would be an overkill for most of the project. I would go with creating new blobs and merging them at the last stage.